# Read R output from memory into matrix (package clickstream)

Tags: r

I am using the R package clickstream to estimate transition probabilities.

The output looks like this:

```
Higher-Order Markov Chain (order=2)

Transition Probabilities:

Lag:  1 
lambda:  1 
                                   A Conversion                        D
A          0,25999823819591261209183          0 0,0605291772381297554784
Conversion 0,02034883720930232703372          0 0,0021747009786154403166
D          0,00162966878083157162491          0 0,6451612903225806272545
E          0,00000000000000000000000          0 0,0000000000000000000000
F          0,00132135306553911205212          0 0,0007249003262051467722
N          0,00603417899929527875441          0 0,0181225081551286693049
Null       0,62182875264270609516615          1 0,1808626313881841196629
O          0,00792811839323467187901          0 0,0094237042406669080385
P          0,00017618040873854828084          0 0,0000000000000000000000
Start      0,00000000000000000000000          0 0,0000000000000000000000
T          0,08073467230443974462784          0 0,0830010873504893054164
                                 E                        F                         N Null
A          0,035714285714285712303 0,0675675675675675713183 0,01131221719457013545618    0
Conversion 0,071428571428571424606 0,0405405405405405427910 0,00061703002879473468293    0
D          0,000000000000000000000 0,0022522522522522522327 0,00102838338132455776874    0
E          0,392857142857142849213 0,0000000000000000000000 0,00000000000000000000000    0
F          0,000000000000000000000 0,3355855855855855995884 0,00123406005758946936586    0
N          0,000000000000000000000 0,0090090090090090089309 0,09543397778691896371495    0
Null       0,214285714285714273819 0,4797297297297297147267 0,86960098724804602010607    0
O          0,000000000000000000000 0,0045045045045045044654 0,00143973673385438096298    0
P          0,000000000000000000000 0,0000000000000000000000 0,00020567667626491157001    0
Start      0,000000000000000000000 0,0000000000000000000000 0,00000000000000000000000    0
T          0,285714285714285698425 0,0608108108108108141865 0,01912793089263677484557    0
                                   O                       P                     Start
A          0,05175117616309461709978 0,059999999999999997780 0,23964753542773373218289
Conversion 0,01568217459487715459421 0,020000000000000000416 0,00000000000000000000000
D          0,00209095661265028742379 0,000000000000000000000 0,01343022430996705478268
E          0,00026136957658128592797 0,000000000000000000000 0,00022068443701823799359
F          0,00156821745948771567626 0,000000000000000000000 0,00345213512192815144206
N          0,00836382645060114969515 0,020000000000000000416 0,06317880168350699376933
Null       0,62859383167799265379472 0,520000000000000017764 0,00000000000000000000000
O          0,20987976999477261919047 0,000000000000000000000 0,04090543671873768383218
P          0,00000000000000000000000 0,320000000000000006661 0,00045713204810920727824
Start      0,00000000000000000000000 0,000000000000000000000 0,00000000000000000000000
T          0,08180867746994249789516 0,059999999999999997780 0,63870805025299892676571
                                   T
A          0,01751190166393681163504
Conversion 0,00991932891453763294909
D          0,00116337808256922864945
E          0,00003061521269919022833
F          0,00048984340318704365329
N          0,00254106265403278904630
Null       0,62369311310790331859266
O          0,00326052015246375932397
P          0,00000000000000000000000
Start      0,00000000000000000000000
T          0,34139023680867025545282

Lag:  2 
lambda:  0 
                                   A Conversion                         D
A          0,31341719077568136464507          0 0,05353982300884956024856
Conversion 0,02154670393664104288689          0 0,00353982300884955747300
D          0,00384346610761705093084          0 0,63628318584070797658825
E          0,00000000000000000000000          0 0,00000000000000000000000
F          0,00279524807826694605267          0 0,00044247787610619468412
N          0,00815280689494526054906          0 0,01548672566371681394437
Null       0,48742138364779874493138          0 0,18008849557522124684716
O          0,01059864896342883715252          0 0,01061946902654867241900
P          0,00058234334963894716659          0 0,00000000000000000000000
Start      0,00000000000000000000000          0 0,00000000000000000000000
T          0,15164220824598181880383          0 0,10000000000000000555112
...
```

Now what I did is write the output into a text file and then read it in as a matrix

```
sink("mc_output.txt")
mc
sink()


# Lag 1
mydat11 = read.table("mc_output.txt", skip = 6, nrows = 11)
mydat12 = read.table("mc_output.txt", skip = 18, nrows = 11)
mydat13 = read.table("mc_output.txt", skip = 30, nrows = 11)
mydat14 = read.table("mc_output.txt", skip = 42, nrows = 11)
...
```

This approach is quite error prone when the dimensions of the matrix change. The idea was to directly read the output from memory. Does anyone have any clever solution how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
library(clickstream)
clickstreams <- c("User1,h,c,c,p,c,h,c,p,p,c,p,p,o",
"User2,i,c,i,c,c,c,d",
"User3,h,i,c,i,c,p,c,c,p,c,c,i,d",
"User4,c,c,p,c,d",
"User5,h,c,c,p,p,c,p,p,p,i,p,o",
"User6,i,h,c,c,p,p,c,p,c,d")
csf <- tempfile()
writeLines(clickstreams, csf)
cls <- readClickstreams(csf, header = TRUE)
mc <- fitMarkovChain(cls)
```

you can for example access the transition matrix using

```
mc@transitions[[1]]
#      c d   h         i o          p
# c 0.32 0 0.8 0.5714286 0 0.47058824
# d 0.12 0 0.0 0.1428571 0 0.00000000
# h 0.04 0 0.0 0.1428571 0 0.00000000
# i 0.12 0 0.2 0.0000000 0 0.05882353
# o 0.00 0 0.0 0.0000000 0 0.11764706
# p 0.40 0 0.0 0.1428571 0 0.35294118
```

The `mc` object has some other slots, too:

```
slotNames(mc)
# [1] "states"                 "order"                  "transitions"            "lambda"                
# [5] "logLikelihood"          "observations"           "start"                  "end"                   
# [9] "transientStates"        "absorbingStates"        "absorbingProbabilities"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. Seems like I couldn't find the syntax for a basic R command

Comment: @lukeA could you please explain how these probabilities are calculated from the clickstream or could you recommend some source where i can refer.

Comment: Please post a new question - I don't know how they are calculated.